# How do I ungrey the "Gemfile" file so that I can open it in Atom?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, atom-editor, rails

I am trying to follow the Project Odin plan to install all necessary things in order to learn how to code.
Idin Project has sent me to: http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app
in order to install these things.
I am stuck at this part:

**Step 2.2: Prepare your rails app for deploying to Heroku**

> *Launch your text editor and open the "Gemfile" file located inside of your test_app folder. (On Windows, this should be in C:\Sites\railsbridge\test_app and on Linux/OS X, it should be under ~/railsbridge/test_app.)*

So I launch Atom. I find the railsbridge testapp folder. I can see the "Gemfile" file but it is greyed out. (showing hidden files setting makes no difference).

#### Question:

*How do I ungrey the "Gemfile" file so that I can open it in Atom?*

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership on the file and its parent directory? Have you tried opening it in a more standard editor such as `nano` or `gedit`?